# A novice question about 60Hz vs 50Hz frequencies in monitors

Tags: monitor

In laptop and desktop PCs monitors have parameters such as 50Hz 60Hz ect.

What is this frequency about?

Is there a DC AC converter inside the computers?

Comment: The image on the screen is refreshed a certain number of times per second. This can be described as a frequency, hence the Hz. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Refresh_rate

Comment: When referring to monitors, that frequency almost certainly relates to the screen refresh rate and has nothing to do with the power supply.

Comment: How about the lamps for the display light? How are they powered? Isn't high-frequency AC needed to be created from DC?

Comment: is electrical engineering only about electronic design? there are thousands of questions about electromagnetism and even cables which has nothing to do with design here. almost none are closed. just wanted to mention i will never agree this inconsistency:))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the screen refresh rate (approximately!).

A little history: Way back in the day when the CRT telly was a new and shiny thing, capacitors were expensive and voltage regulators were very expensive. 
Locking the field rate of the telly cameras to the mains frequency meant that ripple on the power supply due to poor regulation and undersized filter caps in the receiver would cause brightness variations, but that they would be more or less static over time, doing anything else caused very annoying rolling brightness on the display as the supply voltage and scan position beat together.
This of course gave rise to 60Hz frame rates in the US and 50Hz just about everywhere else.

Then colour arrived on the scene and we got another weird split, with the US slightly breaking things by going to 59.97Hz (Due to the way they decided to encode the croma subcarrier), while everyone else stayed on 50Hz.

When computer monitors moved from expensive vector displays to use what were basically repurposed TV technology 50 and 60Hz stuck around (only now we run them non interlaced as a frame rate rather then a field rate).

The backlights on LCD monitors do use high frequency power (If CCFL) but that is usually in the tens of KHz region, not anything that anyone is going to identify as flicker.

Modern high def telly is usually 60Hz because it really does not matter anymore, power conversion is not the costly thing it once was.

Comment: "The backlights on LCD monitors do use high frequency power (If CCFL)" Interesting to know. So there is an DC to AC inverter inside the computer. And do you have an idea why would they use high frequency power to power up the back lights instead of DC?

Comment: The backlight inverter is inside the monitor, and if you are going to step voltage up, you pretty much always start my making it AC or at least pulsed DC (kind of sort of the same thing), then for something like a CCFL lamp you need hundreds of volts at a controlled current which is pretty much the nature of a flyback converter (Which is cheap and simple) so that is what you use, the output waveform is often a mess, but so what? Modern monitors of course use LED backlights which actually also use a switch mode supply, but usually at a rather lower voltage and outputting DC.